# Adding binaries to other peoples conan recipes

Tags: c++, binaries, log4cplus, conan

I'm using given conan packages

```
gtest/1.8.0@bincrafters/stable
boost/1.66.0@conan/stable
log4cplus/2.0.2@bincrafters/stable`
```

and clang (version at least 6.0). 
While first two packages has binaries for clang 6.0, log4cplus doesn't (last is clang 3.9). I don't like the idea that on each workstation I would need to build this package by hand.

How can I upload localy build binary with clang 6.0?
`conan upload` looks promising, however it suggest that it will be NEW package. 
Second question - wouldn't I interfere with package author in any way?

Answer (score 0):

I do recommend open an issue for Bincrafters, requesting clang 3.9 support: https://github.com/bincrafters/community/issues/

Include a new package configuration is just one line in the Travis recipe.

> How can I upload localy build binary with clang 6.0?

You could use JFrog Artifactory, there is a Community Edition with Conan support. Also, you could create a "mirror" for your packages locally with Artifactory, instead to download from Bintray:
https://docs.conan.io/en/latest/uploading_packages/artifactory_ce.html

However, Conan respects your remote list by it order, if your Conan client finds log4cplus first in Bincrafters' remote but the correct binary is only available in your local repository, Conan will ignore your local remote and will show a message error about missed binary package for log4cplus. Thus, in your case, you will need to copy ALL binaries to your local repository.

Regards!

Answer (score 0):

You will find the conan packages installed on your Linux system at `.conan/data/package_name/version/repo_name/tag`. There will be a package folder inside it. If you want to manually add binaries to existing packages then you can add the binary in `/bin` folder in packages.

Or else you can look into the conan recipe in exports folder and look for the package, that from where it is getting its binaries from and add that binary in that path.